# cert-manager-webhook: FailedDiscoveryCheck, namespace hangs in termination

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress, cert-manager

I deleted a namespace that has a service that is exposed with nginx-ingress with a Let's Encrypt certificate controlled by cert-manager. Deletion of the namespace is hanging with status Terminating.

It is likely a problem with the internal API as explained [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/60807#issuecomment-429754733). When I run:

```
kubectl api-resources
```

it returns that the certmanager webhook API isn't reachable:

> error: unable to retrieve the complete list of server APIs: webhook.certmanager.k8s.io/v1beta1: the server is currently unable to handle the request

When I run `kubectl get apiservices v1beta1.webhook.certmanager.k8s.io -o yaml`, for checking its status conditions:

```
...
service:
    name: cert-manager-webhook
    namespace: nginx-ingress
    port: 443
version: v1beta1
versionPriority: 15
status:
conditions:
- lastTransitionTime: "2020-01-21T15:02:23Z"
    message: 'failing or missing response from https://10.24.32.6:10250/apis/webhook.certmanager.k8s.io/v1beta1:
    bad status from https://10.24.32.6:10250/apis/webhook.certmanager.k8s.io/v1beta1:
    404'
    reason: FailedDiscoveryCheck
    status: "False"
    type: Available
```

All nginx-ingress and cert-manager pods are in good health. I have done an update on certmanager in the time that I have deployed and deleted this namespace, which might be an explanation of the issue. How can this problem be solved?

versions:

- Kubernetes: v1.15.4-gke.22
- [cert-manager](https://cert-manager.io/docs/) v0.12.0
- [nginx-ingress](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/nginx-ingress):  1.29.3

Answer (score 1):

A simle solution to solve the issue is presented [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSBS6K_3.1.1/troubleshoot/ns_terminating.html). But this does not describe how such a problem arises or can be prevented.

Create a temporary JSON file that describes the terminating namespace:

```
kubectl get namespace <terminating-namespace> -o json >tmp.json
```

Edit the file `tmp.json` by removing the `kubernetes` value from the `finalizers` field and save the file.

Set a temporary proxy IP and port:

```
kubectl proxy
```

From a new terminal window, make an API call with your temporary proxy IP and port:

```
 curl -k -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT --data-binary @tmp.json http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/v1/namespaces/<terminating-namespace>/finalize
```